# How many reference counts does kobject_create_and_add create?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

According to LDD3, both `kobject_init` and `kobject_add` increase the reference count. So  `kobject_create_and_add` should create an object with 2 references. Right?

But in `linux/sample/kobject/kobject-example.c`, the module `kobject_create_and_add` an object, but only put it once, when exiting. It implies there's only one reference count. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So `kobject_create_and_add` should create an object with 2 references. Right?

Not really. It creates an object (which should set its reference counter to `1`) and then adds it to the *parent* object (which should increment the *parent* object's reference counter). Two different objects are involved, and two different reference counters are handled.

Calling `kobject_put()` decrements the reference counter of the object and, when the new reference counter value tests accordingly, calls `kobject_release()` on the object internally. The latter invokes `kobject_cleanup()`, which, in turn, invokes `kobject_put()` on the *parent* object thus taking care of its reference counter, too.

Comment: Your answer makes sense of everything. On LDD3 Page 369 it says "When a kobject is passed to kobject_add, its reference count is incremented. " I think this is a misleading statement?...